# Multivalue picklist default to multiple selections

Tags: picklist, multi-select

Is this possible? I see the ability to select a single value as the default, *but can I select say 3/5 values as the default?*[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Multi-Select Picklist Field Type](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/field_types.htm#i1435691) documentation:

```
Multi-select picklist fields contain a list of one or more items from which a user can     
choose multiple items. One of the items can be configured as the default item.
```

So based on the documentation alone, I'd say it isn't possible to select more than one default item.

Idea to promote: [Multiple Defaults for Multi-Select Picklist](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrSvAAK)

Comment: weeeakkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: It isn't great, maybe there is an idea that can be promoted?

Answer (score 0):

Jordan,

Assuming $j = jQuery.noConflict();

I'm also using underscore.js here;

```
var selected = ['keys', 'go', 'here'];
$j('#id of select option').filter(function() {
    return _.contains(selected, $(this).text());
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: I don't think we're using `underscore.js` (I don't think it's on default VF pages either but yeah I get where your going)